# How do you short stocks in GTA5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

One of the most interesting elements in GTA5 is the stock market.  I understand that often **Lester** will have assassination missions for the player, such as the one involving the LifeInvader CEO, and was wondering how I could profit off missions such as these?  For example, LifeInvader's stock took quite a hit following the mission, and I was wondering how I could [short sell its stock](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/695/what-is-the-meaning-of-short-selling-or-going-short-a-stock) to make a profit?

Comment: Just a note, you can't trade stocks before the mission where you assassinate the LifeInvader CEO. Trading stocks unlocks a little bit later via Lester. Still a good question to know the answer to.

Comment: @doozer I'm not sure that's true. As Michael, you should be able to trade via the computer in Jimmy's room. I certainly did before lester emailed me the link.

Comment: "Asked: Today. Views: 16445" woah.

Comment: @tombull89 Asked: 5 Days Ago, Viewed: 123265 Times. Someone cashed in man.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, you can profit off of these missions. What you can do is when Lester gives you a mission, he normally says something stock related. The most obvious of which are assassination missions against CEO's. Invest in the opposing companies stock! Once he says something stock related, cancel the mission (if you want ALL characters to invest) and make that stock purchase. Then, the stock you bought will sky-rocket, and allow you to make loads of money.

**LCN Stock Market - Opposing Companies:**

- CoolBeans - BeanMachine
- Burgershot - Up-An-Atom
- Clucking Bell - TacoBomb
- FlyUS - AirEmu
- GoPostal - PostOP
- Bilkington - DollarPills
- Pisswasser - Logger
- MazeBank - BankOfLiberty
- Redwood - Debonaire
- Slaughter, Slaughter & Slaughter - Bullhead
- RadioLosSantos - WorldwideFM
- eCola - Raine

You can find lots more tips on [this thread post here](http://gtaforums.com/topic/594985-the-stock-exchange-information-thread-wip/).

Comment: Excellent info, and I'm sure I will be referencing this info for many hours of gameplay in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all! I'm glad I could help. If you time it correctly, you can make a lot. I'm only 15% in the game, but I have almost 2 million dollars in my wallet for Franklin, because of the stocks.

Comment: +1 for a great answer! Cant wait to try this out and make loads of money.

Comment: I never quite understood how I was supposed to know which car was related to which company. Thanks to your link, I know it wasn't about destroying Feltzers, Stallions or Banshees; it was about destroying vans that have the name Burgershot or Logger, or such imprinted.

Comment: is there a opposing company for vangelico

Comment: I think Zach answered this questions perfectly, but I thought it would be worth it to add [another useful stock market guide](http://geekfed.com/grand-theft-auto-5-stock-market-tips/323).

Comment: I don't know why, but every time I buy stock in Clucking Bell or PostOp and detonate a TacoBomb or GoPostal van, my stocks *sink* and I lose money. Is this answer really accurate, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: First part of Zach's answer really works like a charm. But I have tried everything in the second part (like exploded dozen of FlyUs planes) and never saw any change (sometimes I lost money from AirEmu). I really have reason to believe that Opposing Companies Theory is a GTA V Urban Legend.

Comment: The stuff about opposing companies has long since been debunked -- including on the page that's linked.

Answer (score 12):

No. Unfortunately, there isn't a way to short sell stock in GTA5.

Answer (score 2):

You can't short sell, but when the stocks go down, they will cost less.  IF you buy Lifeinvaders stocks when they are low, you can make a profit later when they release another tech.  You can also go to the airport and destroy some AirEmu planes to make their stock go down and FlyUS stocks will go up.

Comment: Although I've heard the second tip repeatedly, I've never seen actual proof of this.

Comment: You can simply test that by just destroying planes without investing. If it works, buy planes from company that dropped and destroy planes from opposite ;)