# How can you quit a mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Following on from [some advice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131387/how-do-you-short-stocks-in-gta5) about getting all characters to buy shares in a specific company before completing an assassination mission, how do I actually quit a mission? There's only two ways I can see how:

1. Save just before starting a mission, and then load once it's started. The downside here is I need to remember to save before every mission in case one turns out to be important for the stock market.
2. Somehow fail the mission, preferably without committing suicide, where I'm then given the option to Exit.

Comment: I don't know of any methods other than those two either.

Answer (score 2):

Unforunately those are the only two methods.

However, in regards to you forgetting to save before, if you have autosave enabled, just load the autosave and it should load the game before you started the mission, but after everything else (it saves when you complete missions, buy clothes, mod a car, etc.)

Comment: I came here in search of a way to get out of race missions, and I found that you can exit the car your racing in and get into a different car, the mission will immediately fail.

Answer (score 1):

Pause the game and go  across to the online section where you find 'Find New Session'
this will also let you automatically allow you to save the game