# Can you profit on the stock market from Friend Request?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131995/131976) mentions that you can profit from investing at the right time with the right companies related to Lester's assassination missions as Franklin.

Friend Request is the first mission the player does with Lester and its description mentions how Lester will make bank as a shareholder when Jay Norris is assassinated -- it's unclear how, but it's a small detail not mentioned.

In the real world, Facebook (LifeInvader) and Twitter (Bleeter) are sort-of competitors because they are huge moguls in the same sector -- I imagine, if something drastic happened to one, the other might see an opposite reaction in its stock price.

Is this the case in GTA V too? If I buy stock in Bleeter (or a LifeInvader competitor, if there's another), will its price go up for a profit?

I plan to test this and write an answer, but I may as well ask first, in case anyone else knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Life Invader and Bleeter are not competitors. They won't rise/fall with the other's misfortunes.

For a list of all competitors, and what missions you can profit from, go [here.](http://www.gta5cheats.com/stock-market-tips/)

Answer (score 1):

Cyberclaw is correct.

If you want to make some easy cash. Buy 25000 ecola stocks (3-6 bucks) after the friend request mission and sell them when it hits 125 per share. (Later on in the story) Just keep any eye on the stock.

Comment: doesn't work, eCola has been between 100 and 150 the whole game

Comment: I haven't played in some time. Xbox may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Just buy the stocks and keep buying ecola from a vending machine. You buy your own stock back by drinking it and it will increase after every 10 cans of soda. Keep going to that machine or others.